# How to Add a "picture" Link next to the logo in the Header?

Tags: header, link

I am in charge of a Magento website created by a former guy and I followed this tutorial to add a new Picture Link in my header :

https://kamaradski.com/831/how-to-add-a-picture-link-in-magento-header

But it doesn't work, furthermore the " Free Shipping ..." commented in the tutorial is not displayed in my website whereas i didn't comment it out. 
Any ideas of what's wrong ?

The code :

```
<div class="header-container">
<div class="header">
    <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
     <p class="top-promo" title="<?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping on orders over 50$'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping on orders over 50$'); ?></p> 
    <a href="why-us"><img src="/media/upload/logo/WhyOrder.gif" alt="Why Order With Us" align="center" > </a>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
</div>
<div class="quick-access">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?></p>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
```

Here it's what it looks like now

[image: MagentoWebsite]

The red is the picture link added, how could I center it ?

Thanks

Comment: Specify the code which you used.

Comment: Done, as you can see I add the line mentioned under " Free Shipping .. " line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the code below

```
<a href="why-us"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>/media/upload/logo/WhyOrder.gif" alt="Why Order With Us" align="center" > </a>
```

Mage::getBaseUrl() in the image src gets the website base url.

Let me know once its worked.

Comment: it worked, Thanks, now I am trying to center it because the "align" doesn't have any effects on the picture, do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: Post the screenshot of how it looks now.

Comment: Done, as you can see the red is the picture link, but he is blocked next the logo